# How to fix TFS workspace completly corrupted

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

Everything I try to do in Visual Studio in order to manage TFS gives me this message

*TF500232: The change type Edit, Branch, TargetRename is not permitted on uncommitted 
item $/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/Migrations/201707090917286_Rel_1_14_1_1.cs. Please undo the change to this item to fix your local workspace cache.*

I can't anymore checkin / checkout.

Source Control Explorer does not load anymore

Undo does not solve.

I tried to delete tfs cache (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache). Does not solve.

I'm desperate.

Any suggestion will be appreciated...

Comment: You could also use [tf undo command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/undo-command) to do the undo operation next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After retrying step by step all I tried before, finally Undo solved. But I had to do this action multiple times. Last time I did it in Solution Explorer.

(I don't know what exctly solved, if the Undo command was to be launched multiple times, or was to be launched in Solution Explorer instead of Team Explorer...)